# CSS: combine selectors and get the last of them

Tags: css

I need to get the last li that has an `<a>` as child.

```
<li> test A </li>
<li> <a> test B</a> </li>
<li> test C </li>
<li> <a> test D</a> I want to select this one!</li>
<li> test E </li>
<li> test F </li>
```

I would need something like:

(li>a):last-child

```css
li {
  background: #babaca;
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}
li > a {
  background: green;
}

(li>a):last-child {
  background: red;
}

li:last-child{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<li> test A </li>
<li> <a> test B</a> </li>
<li> test C </li>
<li> <a> test D</a> I want to select this one!</li> 
<li> test E </li>
<li> test F </li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: well, the short answer is you cannot with CSS (I mean a generic solution to work no matter the number of li and a are)

Comment: CSS doesn't have any selectors that _ascend_ the tree, only _descend_. (`:has()` is the exception, but is only due to be implemented in JS, and has yet to be done)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no CSS selectors for this. And no combination of existing selectors can do it either. You best bet is to use JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other's have commented, this isn't possible with CSS at this time. The `:has` pseudo-class selector might provide for a way down the road.

In the meantime, here are a few options:

## #1 Use [jQuery's `:has` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```js
$("li:has(a):last").addClass("last");
```

```css
li {
  background: #babaca;
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}

li > a {
  background: green;
}

li.last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="list">
  <li> test A </li>
  <li> <a> test B</a> </li>
  <li> test C </li>
  <li> <a> test D</a> I want to select this one!</li>
  <li> test E </li>
  <li> test F </li>
</ul>
```

## #2 A small plain JavaScript function to find and apply a `.last` class to the last `li > a` element.

The function `findLastA()` accepts a selector to target a `ul` element, then finds the last `li` containing an `a` element, and applies the `.last` class to it.

Keep in mind this is made specifically for the HTML structure outlined in the question.

```js
function findLastA(el) {
  var listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(el + " > li"));
  for (let i = listItems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let childNodes = listItems[i].children;
    if (childNodes.length && childNodes[0].tagName === "A") {
      listItems[i].classList.add("last")
      break;
    }
  }
}

// Call the function
findLastA("#list");
```

```css
li {
  background: #babaca;
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
}

li > a {
  background: green;
}

li.last {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li> test A </li>
  <li> <a> test B</a> </li>
  <li> test C </li>
  <li> <a> test D</a> I want to select this one!</li>
  <li> test E </li>
  <li> test F </li>
</ul>
```